# Disabled fields are not disabled/reset when page reload from validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've set certain fields to be disabled when a checkbox is checked. But when a user submits the form data and it's invalid, page is reloaded, where the checkbox remains checked but the fields are no longer disabled. Not sure how I can fix this?

The javascript:

```
$('#CommentFrequencyOk').on('click', function () {
    $('#test').prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

The fields to be disabled:

```
<fieldset id="test">
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('frequency_remarks'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('duration_remarks'); ?>
</fieldset>
```

And the checkbox:

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label for="CommentFrequencyOk">
        <input type="hidden" name="data[Comment][frequency_ok]" id="CommentFrequencyOk_" value="0" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[Comment][frequency_ok]" class="checkbox" value="1" id="CommentFrequencyOk" /> Frequency
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: did u try attr('disabled','this.checked') instead of  prop('disabled', this.checked);

Comment: just did. It doesn't work I'm afraid.

Comment: try this one prop('disabled', true);

Comment: Now once the box's checked, the fields are permanently disabled even if it's unchecked later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the following line on page load also i.e.

```
// On Page Load
  $('#test').prop('disabled', $('#CommentFrequencyOk').is(":checked"));
```

Comment: Thanks. But how exactly do I set the codes above on page load?

Comment: Write this line inside 
$( document ).ready(function() {
   // console.log( "ready!" );
});

Answer (score 0):

Note that during the initial form filling, the fields were disabled by the even handler for the click event on the checkbox. However, since the checkbox is already enabled, the event handler was never called and the fields remained enabled.

While rendering the page using PHP, you can simply disable the field there itself during page reload.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this. But if I disabled the fields with PHP, a user may not enable them after.

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the script in page load

```
$(function(){
$('#test').prop('disabled', $('#CommentFrequencyOk').is(":checked"));
});
```

Comment: The main problem of your code loading the script only. So you should load the functionality while loading the form itself.,

Answer (score 0):

Page reload checkbox checked and div#test is disabled if checkbox selected. You can try by flowing code.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#CommentFrequencyOk').on('click', function () {
  $('#test').prop('disabled', this.checked);
 });
 });
</script>

<fieldset id="test" <?php if(@$_GET['data']['Comment']['frequency_ok'] == 1): echo 'disabled'; endif; ?>>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('frequency_remarks'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('duration_remarks'); ?>
</fieldset>

<div class="checkbox">
    <form >
    <label for="CommentFrequencyOk">
        <input type="hidden" name="data[Comment][frequency_ok]" id="CommentFrequencyOk_" value="0" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="data[Comment][frequency_ok]" class="checkbox" value="1" id="CommentFrequencyOk" <?php if(@$_GET['data']['Comment']['frequency_ok'] == 1): echo 'checked'; endif; ?> /> Frequency
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```